# How to filter standard error from a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using `Popen` to run an external process.  Here is a deliberately simple example to illustrate; `ls` writes to standard output, and to standard error for each missing file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def test_process(*command):
    process = Popen(command)
    process.communicate()

test_process('ls', '/etc/hosts', 'bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3')
```

Output as follows:

```
/etc/hosts
ls: cannot access 'bad1': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'bad2': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'bad3': No such file or directory
```

However, I would like to filter out certain lines from standard error, so I need to pass something into the `stderr` parameter of the `Popen` constructor.

According to the Python documentation (and confirmed by stepping through the code in an IDE) the `stderr` parameter can only be `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an integer file descriptor or a file-like object wrapping a (valid) file descriptor.  I tried creating a class and passing a new instance in `stderr`, with the idea of implementing the missing methods to do the filtering; but that doesn't work because its `fileno` method has to return an actual file descriptor.

So I think I need to pass `stderr=PIPE` instead, and do the filtering on the other end of the pipe that gets created.  This was my attempt:

```
def test_process(*command):
    process = Popen(command, stderr=PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if error:
        lines = error.decode().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            if '2' not in line:
                print(line, file=sys.stderr)
```

However, while I don't expect standard error to contain a lot of lines, it would be more elegant to filter it on the fly.  Is there some way I can write some Python code that receives one line at a time, and either discards it or passes it on?  I suppose I could create a new subprocess to do the filtering, and chain another `Popen` onto the first one, but that seems pretty heavyweight for the task.

I certainly don't want to interrupt the standard output stream, which is being written to the actual console, so I can't just read one line at a time from standard error, the way I might for standard output.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Do you need `stdout` from the process? It's a little bit trickier to get right without deadlocks when you need both streams

Comment: Yes. I'm piping `tar` output to `ssh` and unpacking it on the remote host, and I want to remove the "This computer system is the property of" warning because it clutters up the output when I'm connecting to multiple hosts. So I want to see everything written to `stdout`, and all actual errors written to `stderr`.